# Wicket form triggering a download

Tags: forms, download, wicket

I am working with Wicket, trying to create a form where users choose options which correspond to files, which are then merged when the form is submitted and are presented to the user. Currently, the `onSubmit()` code for the form looks something like this:

```
ResourceStreamRequestHandler mergedFileHandler = new ResourceStreamRequestHandler(new FileResourceStream(mergedFiles));
mergedFileHandler.setFileName(mergedFiles.getName());
getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(mergedFileHandler);
```

This works fine when the Submit button is clicked once as the file is offered for download, but when clicked again the page seems to reload itself and the `onSubmit()` method is not run. Is there a better way to do this, so the user can make changes and re-submit the form to get a different download without having to reload the page or re-enter their options?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using AjaxSubmitLink, and then make sure you do not return the file names? It seems like you reload the entire form, and the file names are cleared during reload.